# c++ scope of variable in constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

I have 2 class `classNode` and `classTree`.
In my classTree constructor I create a `vector<classNode> nodes` and pushed
back `classNodes` objects.

Then I assigned a `classNode*` pointer to first member of
`vector<classNode>`:

```
this->root= &nodes[0];
```

Now after quiting constructor my pointer shows garbage, but I have to use
it. Could I use `static vector<classNode> nodes` for this purpose ? Or is
there anyone to give me any advice ?

**EDIT**

```
struct nodeInfo{
    string name;
    int tab;
};
ClassTree(){

    vector<nodeInfo> container;
         vector<ClassNode> nodes;
         //assume that container is a not-empty vector.I removed this part for simplicity.
         for(int i=0;i<container.size();i++){
          nodes.push_back(ClassNode (container[i].name,1));
    }

    this->root=&nodes[0];

}

ClassTree::function2(){

//now I want to use root here. I mean I want to reach &nodes[0] here.
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow Rule of Thumb #3: "Now, as you all know" is followed by some complete misconception.

Comment: can you show the code of the `classTree` constructor?

Comment: @KerrekSB - along with the `which is obviously true..` and `democratic republic of...` etc

Comment: When nodes is a member of `classTree`, why can't you get the root via nodes[0] when you need it? why explcitly store it?
(it seems like you're using an array to store your tree. why not use a tree structure instead)?
eitherways, please attach some code. don't make us imagine everything you might have done.

Comment: You don't give the defintion of your class and constructor, and the code you do give is not correct (as noted earlier by Mat). If you want help, start by writing a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @EdHeal: My favourite: "My program is working perfectly. Only one thing:" (UB follows)

Comment: nodes is not a member of classTree @Raja

Answer (score 3):

If I'm getting the scenario currectly (showing the code will help a lot).
you shouldn't create a `vector<classNode> nodes` in the constructor but have it as a member of `classTree`. that's go for `root` as well.

==EDIT==

Now after seeing your code, you should change it to:

you should either move `vector<ClassNode> nodes;` to the class in the header file.

if you can't change the header (is that a class homework ?) you should change the way you build it by having a `left` and `right` pointers in the `nodeInfo` struct. that's way having the root will gain you access to all the Tree mambers. moreover you must allocate the new nodes with `new` rather than having a parameters on the stack and point them:

```
struct nodeInfo
{
    string name;
    int tab;
    nodeInfo *left;
    nofeInfo *right;
};

ClassTree(){

    vector<nodeInfo> container;
    vector<ClassNode> nodes;

    for(int i=0;i<container.size();i++)
    {
        nodeInfo newNode = new nodeInfo;// <-- use `new` so it will "live" out side the scope.
        newNode.name = ...;
        newNode.tab = ...;

        //here is the "magic" when you actually need to build the tree.
        //if it's the first one then root should point it.
        //otherwise it should be one of the root's childs
        //but you can't expect me to do everything for you (:
    }

    this->root=&nodes[0];

}

ClassTree::function2(){

//now I want to use root here. I mean I want to reach &nodes[0] here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do not change the header , root is a member of classTree btw. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you've pushed elements into a vector in stack space in your constructor.
Then assigned a member pointer to element 0.
As soon as your constructor returns, the pointer becomes invalid. It was on the stack - it no longer is.

Comment: you really ought to describe what you want to do. why is your constructor doing what it is? only then can we help.

Comment: I need to reach vector<classNodes> nodes via root pointer in another method of classTree. Thats it. @Raja

Comment: If you want to create it in the constructor then you need to store that vector<classNodes> as a member variable. Otherwise you could move it to an ordinary function and return it from there.

Comment: @caesar : i understand that. how does your constructor get this vector in the first place? your code shows you initializing it - if so, why dont you just make it a class member?

Comment: Do you need to have the nodes in a vector? Looks to me like you’re asked to do explicit heap allocations and deallocations. Which modern C++ code doesn’t do much of, but it still can be useful.